# integrating bootstrap in angular X project

Tags: angular6

When including bootstrap into an angular 2+ project is it better to include the script in the angular.json file or include a link to the bootstrap CDN in the index.html file?

Comment: In my opinion, if you are building an offline application and want to use jquery, bootsrap... then install via npm and add it to angular. Otherwise, cdn would be faster for the end user, as well as your deplyment package will slightly smaller.

Comment: yea that is a good point offline vs online apps, I'm used to using a CDN solution, mostly on very popular libraries because that may be already cached in the users device and make things work faster.  I wonder if/how a CDN linked item would affect server side rendering... I've using npm modules like ng-bootstrap in order to avoid jQuery in preparation for when I implement server side rendering.